# Laptop freezes after suspend

Tags: suspend, crash

Recently I've experienced a problem with my laptop. It suspended perfectly after closing the lid, and everything was ok after opening it.

The issue is that now the laptop freezes when I suspend it (or close the lid). The screen goes to black (but bright black, it is not off) and the laptop remains on. I've tried changing the drivers to the NVIDIA one (like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882843/system-freeze-after-suspend)) but nothing new, and I also tried to change`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, but the same.

I would also like to point out that I've been recently installing a couple of VMs in VirtualBox so that I had to enable the virtualization and the booting in insecure mode, just in case it has something to do with my problem.

And also, a couple of times I could read a message kind of `Freezing of tasks failed after 20.01 seconds (3 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0)` after suspend.

I would apreciate your help.

Technical details:

- Lenovo U31
- Intel Core i5 5200U CPU 2.20 GHz
- Linux 4.10.0-32-generic

**UPDATE:** Some output.

```
jorge@jorge-Lenovo-U31-70:~$ ls -alt /var/crash/
total 2656
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 ago 16 18:14 .
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     whoopsie       0 ago 16 18:14 .lock
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 ago 12 18:16 _usr_lib_virtualbox_VirtualBox.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie       0 ago 12 18:16 _usr_lib_virtualbox_VirtualBox.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie 2660216 ago 12 18:15 _usr_lib_virtualbox_VirtualBox.0.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 ago 12 14:52 _usr_sbin_update-apt-xapian-index.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie       0 ago 12 14:52 _usr_sbin_update-apt-xapian-index.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   45613 ago 12 14:52 _usr_sbin_update-apt-xapian-index.0.crash
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root        4096 ago 12 14:40 ..


jorge@jorge-Lenovo-U31-70:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Memoria:        7,7G        660M        6,5G        137M        590M        6,7G
Swap:          7,9G          0B        7,9G


jorge@jorge-Lenovo-U31-70:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda3                               partition   8299516 0   -1


 jorge@jorge-Lenovo-U31-70:~$ sudo blkid           
/dev/sda1: UUID="8BFC-B5D5" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="afdaf7bb-755c-46d8-80d2-247bec22b9c3"
/dev/sda2: UUID="99c6efde-2951-471d-954e-9250b95605d6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="24463a23-fe3d-4904-b687-ee2a0bed4968"
/dev/sda3: UUID="85f4ca7a-9e8f-42c1-ab7d-765e18fae6a4" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="39c2bbcd-4868-477b-8c31-3032c613c201"


jorge@jorge-Lenovo-U31-70:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=99c6efde-2951-471d-954e-9250b95605d6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8BFC-B5D5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=85f4ca7a-9e8f-42c1-ab7d-765e18fae6a4 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Today ago 16 I have experienced the freeze lots of times. When freezing, no text is shown in the screen if I press ESC, but if I press the power buttom then the elementary symbol appears in screen (as in the booting), and if I press ESC there, then I obtain some text:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: After another freeze (and turning the laptop off with the power button), I start the laptop and I get a error message related to the suspend:[image: Elementary has experienced an internal error]

Comment: This will be a little difficult to troubleshoot long distance, but lets try a few things. 1) try to suspend it, when it freezes, hit the ESC key... does it bring you to a text screen? 2) show me `ls -alt /var/crash` and `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Copy/paste that output into your question, not the comments please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have the info for me.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` - it will leed you to the scripts the system runs when you Suspend, Hibernate, UnSuspend and UnHibernate. These scripts are meant to "help". You may have to adjust one, or write your own.

Comment: @Minkowski see my partial answer. Report back.

Comment: Is this Elementary Linux, or what Ubuntu flavor/version?

Comment: @heynnema yes, this is Elementary OS Loki, based on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: @Minkowski technically, we don't support Elementary OS here, even if it is a Ubuntu derivative... but here we are :-)

Comment: @heynnema I know and that's why  I really, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

In `terminal`...

- `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` # if exists, show me the contents
- `dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii` # see if this is installed, if not:

  - `sudo dpkg -i intel-microcode`
- `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak` # backup fstab file
- `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` # edit fstab

change this line:

```
UUID=8BFC-B5D5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

to this:

```
UUID=8BFC-B5D5  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

Then reboot. Retest suspend.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download the free memory diagnostic and run **at least** one full pass.

**Update #1:**

- start the `Disks` application
- select the disk in the left pane
- click on the "hamburger" icon
- select `SMART Data & Tests`
- review the data
- run the tests

**Update #2:**

- `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` looks fine
- we installed `intel-microcode`

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

**Update #3:**

- go to https://www.memtest86.org
- download the free memory diagnostic
- run at least one complete pass

**Update #4:**

- check your motherboard BIOS version and go to the manufacturer's web site and make sure it's the latest version for your make/model #. If not, update it asap.

**Update #5:**

- we found that the suspend problem didn't occur when we disconnected the wireless and used a wired connection
- we uninstalled the broadcom wl kernel module that was tainting the kernel
- we'll also replace the r8169 driver

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

pending sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms

pending BIOS update
```

Comment: I'm afraid suspend doesn't work yet... About the first code, here you are: `jorge@jorge-Lenovo-U31-70:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=UUID=85f4ca7a-9e8f-42c1-ab7d-765e18fae6a4` . I changed the line but my laptop still freezes before suspending. And please check the URL you sent me because I get a spam webpage (facebook sort).

Comment: @Minkowski your resume file looks fine. Did you check the `intel-microcode`? Sorry about the bad URL, I've fixed it.

Comment: @Minkowski please do the memtest, and update #1 in my answer.

Comment: Having `intel-microcode` installed (checked), I ran `dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii` but I obtain nothing, no text is shown.

Comment: @Minkowski then you need to install it. `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` then reboot, and retest.

Comment: **Update**: When restarting the laptop after a freeze, I have just obtained a error message related with suspend/resume failure. I will add it to the question, I feel like it might be the key.

Comment: Off we go, `jorge@jorge-Lenovo-U31-70:~$ dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii`  
`ii  intel-microcode 3.20151106.1 amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs`

Comment: @Minkowski I haven't seen the newest error message yet...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64000/discussion-between-minkowski-and-heynnema).