# Ubuntu unable to wake up after suspending

Tags: 16.04, suspend, freeze, 18.04, bug-reporting

**Issue:**

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my MSI computer *(because linux > default windows duhh)* but whenever the computer Suspends, it can't un-suspend
the screen is just dark, though you can hear the computer running
and it doesn't matter how many times I press space or any other key, only option I have is to power it off and back on

**What I have tried:**

The video this guy posted a long time ago looks exactly like my problem but with an older version:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEsF72DPLSo

- In the comments the mentions how he fixed his issue, though after following those steps, I wasn't able to fix it either.
- I tried the solution I found here: [System freeze after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882843/system-freeze-after-suspend)
  But this also hasn't fixed it

Any and all help is very much appreciated!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html.en. If you issue following command in your terminal, what does it say? `journalctl -p crit`