# How to solve black screen after suspension or lock screen with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-gnome, bug-reporting, ubuntu-drivers

Hi everyone I just installed Ubuntu 22.04, every time I suspend or lock my screen there is a black screen and I have to force shutdown.

I have NVIDIA 940MX

I have tried all the options on the Internet to downgrade the version from 510 to 470,390
, I tried to reconfigure the grub and I changed gdm to lightdm. Nothing worked out
I tried those solutions:

1. [System freeze after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882843/system-freeze-after-suspend)
2. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-suspend-resuming-and-wakeup-with-nvidia370-28/45282
3. [how to solve black screen after suspension with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405262/how-to-solve-black-screen-after-suspension-with-ubuntu-22-04-lts)

I've been trying for almost 2 days nothing is working can someone please help me and guide me to solve this problem

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: while in black screen, press ctrl+alt+f1 simultaneously; wait a couple of seconds and the login screen should appear. In the event if it doesn't work, kindly indicate what configurations you are in now since you mentioned you've tried a few of them.

Comment: When I close my screen, lock or suspend the laptop freeze and I'm not able to use my keyboard, well I undo all the configuration because nothing worked out, I'm using Nvidia 510 latest driver

Answer (score 7):

Solution that worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-resume.service

sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume.service

sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia
```

Detailed answer:
[how to solve black screen after suspension with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405262/how-to-solve-black-screen-after-suspension-with-ubuntu-22-04-lts)

Comment: on top of this update of grub helped: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep

Comment: I used this, but now my system doesn't suspend at all :(

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to disable **nvidia**'s services in **systemctl**?

To display a list of all services from nvidia:

> systemctl list-unit-files | grep nvidia

I have this output:

> nvidia-hibernate.service                   disabled        enabled

> nvidia-persistenced.service                static          -

> nvidia-resume.service                      disabled        enabled

> nvidia-suspend.service                     disabled        enabled

where first column is the name of the service,
second column is the current state and the last one is the vendor's preset.

If those services are **enabled** you could try to **disable** them:

> sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate

> sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume

> sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However, yes I tried that same same nothing changed at all

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, my HTPC does not suspend or lock, I just turn off the TV when I'm not watching. Each morning I would find the black screen and have to force shutdown (or you can get a shell and `sudo systemctl restart gdm`).

In the end I have worked around this problem and am very happy, here's what I did:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop -y
```

That replaces gdm with lightdm (you should make it your default when asked during setup).

My setup:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Nvidia GTX1650
- Nvidia driver: nvidia-driver-515 (from PPA)

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you tried removing nvidia drivers and then checking if the issue persists?
2. Could you paste the output of `nvidia-smi`?
3. Have you tried by reinstalling the drivers?

I would install a suitable version of nvidia driver (for e.g. nvidia-driver-470) along with cuda toolkit (11.2 or 11.4) using instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#) and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#). In the instructions, you can follow the commands for Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 0):

With my ASUS Zenbook Pro 15 UX550 with a GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile, in order to get it working again,  I had to downgrade to the Nvidia driver nvidia-driver-470 (meta) package and follow the instructions in the setup script [here](https://gist.github.com/bmcbm/375f14eaa17f88756b4bdbbebbcfd029).

Comment: Not an answer as the OP has said in the question they tried the driver you suggest.

Comment: I disagree - It points to a driver combination with a scripted solution, that has worked for 22.04.  The script and the associated conversation that I have pointed to with https://gist.github.com/bmcbm/375f14eaa17f88756b4bdbbebbcfd029 shows a history of solving what would appear to be a related problem - please look again.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue was with me. It seems my monitor is missing the proper information to wake up from the PC, so I tried to change my HDMI cable, and yes, it works. Before, I was using a cheap $1.7 HDMI cable.

although there was no problem with the VGA port or cable.